# How to integrate openId with devise in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, devise

I'm new to rails and just got a simple devise setup working.  I'm looking to implement something that still uses the core devise feature set but would allow login via openid provider rather than "register w/ email or username"

How might I get started with this using the latest devise gem and rails 3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the [devise_openid_authenticatable](http://github.com/nbudin/devise_openid_authenticatable) gem.