# Devise + Google Apps OAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to add Google Apps authentication to my Rails (3) app using Devise (1.2.1).  Thing is, I can't find anything that helpful on the interwebs other than the small mention in the devise wiki.

Question is, is this possible, and are there any examples out there I can check out?

Comment: This question was asked in the google group
http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/4cda31d384b4c976 There are links to examples

Comment: Duplicate of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700996/how-to-integrate-openid-with-devise-in-rails-3
Unless OP clarifies if he needs OAuth or OpenId

Comment: Also related to this older question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017901/whats-the-correct-configuration-line-to-get-devise-omniauth-and-google-working

Answer (score 1):

Devise is to make your web application authenticate users. If you wanт users to login into your app with Google ID then look into `OpenID`. If you want to connect to Google services you need to implement `Oauth` client

Comment: Yes, indeed - hence why I'm asking for examples.

Comment: You need to describe your use case in more details.

Comment: Thanks for this, this made it more clear for me. I think I need OpenID and not Oauth since I only want users to login using their google apps ID.  I don't want to interactive with google services other than authorization.